# Initialise components with custom names

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a view that contains 15 images and labels . 
I ve put them all on view but in some cases I don t want to show them all . 
For example I have 
IBOutlet UIImageView* image1 ;
....................* image2 ;
......................
.....................*imagen;

I have a list with objects but if i don t have n objects and i have just m i don t want to show images from m  to n.
In for loop I would like to have something 
- > string componentToShow = "image" + i ;
and now (componentToShow).....set to visible and diffrent prop .

Thanks, 
Raluca

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you've got a varying number of objects, and you want to display accompanying views for the objects you have.  You have laid out the maximum number of accompanying views in a nib file, and are now struggling with hiding the ones you don't want.  Is that correct?

I would do it like this:

Take the accompanying views out of the nib.  Create a second nib that represents a single object (e.g. label and image together).  In your view controller's `viewDidLoad` method, load the nib representing an object and store it in an instance variable.  When an event happens that creates a new object, instantiate the nib and add the views produced to your view controller's view hierarchy.

Alternatively, if your representation of objects is simple enough, skip the second nib, and simply create the views directly in code.

Comment: I ve done another nib that contains the label and the image . You have right it is more clean like this . In my main class I have now a controller to this..And in loop I will probably to add subview...But how I compute coordonates? Should I predifine them in a dictionary , or maybe should I have a formula that use the iterator ?

Comment: You don't need a controller for the second nib, you are just adding them to your existing view controller's hierarchy, so your existing view controller should handle them.  As for layout, it depends on how you want them to be laid out.  In a row?  In a grid?  In a column?

Comment: In a grid....I do this with add subview ?....MyImageVC *vc = [.....]; For(int i =0;...){ vc.labelText= aaa; self.view.addSubview:vc.view } Something like this and something is missing ....the way how i put them in a grid

Comment: Yes, you can add them to the view hierarchy with `addSubview:`.  To lay them out in a grid, find the position in the grid for an item by taking its position in the list and using division to find its vertical position and modulo to find its horizontal position.  Then multiply by the width/height of the individual items.  You can then use `setFrame:` on the items to place them in the correct position.

Comment: is there another method ..so i don t use addsubview ?

Comment: If you want to add a subview, you should use `addSubview:`.  Why don't you want to use `addSubview:`?